# Quick regex pattern in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have a large string chunk of text, and I need to extract all occurrences of text matching the following pattern:

`QXXXXX-X` (where X can be any digit, 0-9).

How do I do this in PHP?

```
<?php
preg_match_all("","Q05546-8 XXX Q13323-0",$output,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($output);
?>
```

Comment: Try something, otherwise you don't even know if you can write it by yourself

Comment: Ok just found a generator! thanks

Comment: `preg_match_all('~Q\d{4}-\d~',"Q05546-8 XXX Q13323-0",$output,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);`

Comment: It should be `\d{5}-\d` ...

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Maybe `Q(\d+-\d+)`? can the numbers be of any length? https://regex101.com/r/wP7xE8/1

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
preg_match_all('/\bQ[0-9]{5}-[0-9]\b/',"Q05546-8 XXX Q13323-0",$output,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($output);
```

Or, you can use shorthand class `\d` for a digit: `\bQ\d{5}-\d\b`.

**Regex explanation**:

- `\b` - Word boundary (we are either at the beginning of between a word character (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and a non-word one (all others)
- `Q` - Literal case-sensitive `Q`
- `[0-9]{5}` - Exactly 5 (due to `{5}`) digits from `0` to `5` range
- `-` - Literal hyphen
- `[0-9]` - Exactly 1 digit from `0` to `5`
- `\b` - Again a word boundary.

If you have these values inside longer sequences, you may consider using `\bQ[0-9]{5}-[0-9](?![0-9])` or using shorthand classes, `\bQ\d{5}-\d(?!\d)`.

Output of the [demo](http://ideone.com/y1TZiC):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Q05546-8
            [1] => Q13323-0
        )

)
```